# Can I have two .gitconfig files?

Tags: git

I've have two repos: a private one and one for my work. The problem is that Eclipse loads the file from `C:\Users\user\` and I am not able to change this location.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can configure settings in the git repo (`.git/config`) itself and they will override your global settings. That is the path on unix systems, I'm not certain about Windows. On a unix systems you can use `git config --local` to specify to use the local repo config instead of the global config.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The C:\Users\user... file is your **global** configuration which you configure with:

```
git config --global setting=value
```

You can override the settings per repository (thus generating a .gitconfig) in each repository, by running the same `git config` command, inside the repository, without the `--global` flag.

```
git config setting=value
```

Tip: For me, the only thing that really changes between work projects and personal projects on my machine is the e-mail that goes on each commit, so what works very well for me is to [**not** set any e-mail on the global .gitconfig to force Git to ask me which e-mail I want to use per repository](https://github.com/caioproiete/dotfiles/blob/master/git/.gitconfig-windows-template#L1-L5).

[I've also created a couple of aliases](https://github.com/caioproiete/dotfiles/blob/master/git/.gitconfig-windows-template#L57-L59): `git for-work` and `git for-fun` which I run for every repository and it configures the right e-mail for me.

---

For reference: [My .gitconfig templates for Windows and OSX](https://github.com/caioproiete/dotfiles/tree/master/git)